# Reading multiple values in a PDF417 barcode

Tags: capture, kofax

I have a PDF417 barcode that contains multiple values delimited by a semicolon. How can I get Kofax 10 to read those values as two separate index fields? I've created my index zone:

[image: Barcode Index Zone, but only one field to associate]

Is this done only through a script, or is there some setting I can use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: If I recall correctly from certification-training, you'd assign the full value to two fields and cut away the unwanted parts via script respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You read the code into a field (no need to assign it to two fields). Create a document validation script that gets the value of the field during the Document PreProcess event and copies the required parts to the fields of your choice. You need to use the Validation module in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Was able to combine both field values into a single barcode and used the PreProcess event.

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted, if you have the time. Thank you.